# Show value of element in Debug state to Visual Studio Code [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, debugging

Not long ago changed IDE from Android Studio to **VisualStudio Code** to practice Flutter, I am still learning the commands and resources of VSCode.

Today I discovered that it does **not show me the values** of my variables in the **Debug state**,
Show Me message

**optimized out**

**Invalid params**,

does anyone know what configuration is needed?

[image]
thank you.

Comment: Comment posted as answer by [@LOODAN](/users/20545194): "_Have you defined the types of data? hero which data type and heros which type of list. I think https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems will help you._"

Comment: yes, I specify the type of List which works with Strings

Comment: There's an issue about this at https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/52430.